# Matrix-vector norm inequalities in tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-norms, tridiagonal-matrices

Let's consider the linear system $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$, with $A$ being a diagonally dominant by columns and tridiagonal matrix, that is:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} d_1&& c_2    &&        &&        &&      \\
                    a_1&& d_2    && c_3    &&        &&      \\
                       && \ddots && \ddots && \ddots &&      \\
                       &&        && a_{n-2}&& d_{n-1}&& c_{n}\\
                       &&        &&        && a_{n-1}&& d_n \end{pmatrix}$$

with $a_n=c_1=0$. Prove that $K\|\vec{x}\|_{\infty} \leq \|\vec{b}\|_{\infty}$ is satisfied, where $$K = \min\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} \left\{|d_i|-|a_i|-|c_i| \right\}$$

---

I've tried using the property $$\|\vec{b}\|_{\infty} = \|A\vec{x}\|_{\infty} \leq \|A\|_{\infty} \|\vec{x}\|_{\infty}$$ but I don't get anywhere near the answer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something wrong in the description.
As it is, the statement is false and a counter example is provided by
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 0\\ 0 & 3 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\quad
\vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix}2\\ -\frac12\\ 0 \end{pmatrix},
$$
which gives $K=1$, $\Vert\vec{x}\Vert_{\infty} = 2$ and $\Vert\vec{b}\Vert_{\infty} = \frac32$.

Conversely, if one considers $A^{\top}\vec{x}=\vec{b}$, then one can prove the inequality as follows. If $K=0$, the inequality is trivially satisfied. We can therefore assume $K>0$ in the following, which means that $A^\top$ is *strictly* diagonally dominant (by row) and therefore invertible [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix#Applications_and_properties)]. Hence we can write
$$
\Vert\vec{x}\Vert_{\infty} = \Vert A^{-\top}\vec{b}\Vert_{\infty}
\le
\Vert A^{-\top}\Vert_{\infty} \, \Vert\vec{b}\Vert_{\infty},
$$
where the inequality follows from the standard property of matrix norms induced by vector norms [[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms)].
We then use Theorem 1 in [[3](https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(75)90112-3)], which states: "Assume $A$ is diagonally dominant by rows and set $\alpha = \min_k(\vert a_{kk} \vert - \sum_{j\neq k} \vert a_{kj} \vert)$. Then $\Vert A^{-1}\Vert_{\infty}<1/\alpha$" (note: they must have a typo because the inequality is actually not strict). We apply their theorem to our $A^\top$ and obtain that
$$
\Vert A^{-\top}\Vert_{\infty} \le 1/K.
$$
This gives
$$
\Vert\vec{x}\Vert_{\infty}
\le
\frac1K \Vert\vec{b}\Vert_{\infty}.
$$
Rearranging proves the (modified, i.e. for $A^\top$ rather than $A$) statement of the question.

Comment: Is A a tridiagonal matrix? For it to be it must have non zero values in the main diagonal and in the 2 subdiagonals over and under it. I think this does not fulfill the requirements of the exercise.

Comment: It is tridiagonal. There's no requirement for the main diagonal and two subdiagonals to be nonzero. For example a diagonal matrix is also tridiagonal (as well as upper and lower triangular, although the strictly triangular parts are zero). Anyway, even with your more restrictive definition, you can take my example and set elements (2,1), (2,3) and (3,2) to 0.001 and see that the claim is still false.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about the problem and I got here:

Let's consider $$K||x||_{\infty}\leq ||b||_{\infty}=||Ax||_{\infty}\leq||A||_{\infty}·||x||_{\infty}$$
Simplifying, it results in:
$$K\leq||A||_{\infty}$$
or $$1\leq \dfrac{||A||_{\infty}}{K}$$
Given that $$||A||_{\infty}=\text{max}_{i\leq j \leq n}\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|=|d_j|+|a_j|+|c_j|$$ for some $j\in\mathbb{N}$
and that $$K = \min\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} \left\{|d_i|-|a_i|-|c_i| \right\}=|d_i|-|a_i|-|c_i|$$ for some $i\in\mathbb{N}$

We can rewrite the third inequality as
$$1\leq\dfrac{|d_j|+|a_j|+|c_j|}{|d_i|-|a_i|-|c_i|}$$
We know that because A is a tridiagonal matrix that
$$|d_i|\geq |a_i|+|c_i|$$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$

That is $$|d_i|-|a_i|-|c_i|\geq 0$$

Then we have two possibilities $i=j$ or $i\neq j$

If $i=j$ then $|d_j|+|a_j|+|c_j|\geq |d_j|-|a_j|-|c_j|$

Now, $K$ is defined as the minimum of the difference of $|d_i|-|a_i|-|c_i|$ so it follows that if $i\neq j$ then $|d_j|+|a_j|+|c_j|\geq |d_i|-|a_i|-|c_i|$.

So we have proven that $1\leq \dfrac{||A||_{\infty}}{K}$ and thus the first statement.

Is this solution correct?

Comment: That looks fine to me.

Comment: Your expression for $\Vert A\Vert_{\infty}$ is incorrect. That's actually $\Vert A\Vert_1$. As I said in my answer, I think the statement is incorrect. I managed to prove it but for $A^\top \vec{x}=\vec{b}$.

Comment: I see, the correct version would be ∥A∥∞=d_i+c_{i+1}+a_{i−1}?

Comment: Correct. ======

Comment: Also, there's a small oversight: the statement "We know that because A is a tridiagonal matrix that" should be "We know that because A is diagonally dominant by columns that".

Comment: Looking at your proof again... actually the very first assertion is incorrect. (explanation below)

Comment: You want to prove that $K||x||_{\infty}\leq ||b||_{\infty}$ and know that $||Ax||_{\infty}\leq||A||_{\infty}·||x||_{\infty}$; you say that this means that you just need to prove that $K\leq ||A||_{\infty}$. Doing this your proof uses as a fact something that you are are trying to prove and you get a circular argument. You are basically saying that you can prove that $f(x)<g(x)$ if you know that $g(x)<h(x)$ and are able to prove that $f(x)<h(x)$ (since $f(x)<g(x)<h(x)$). Replace $f(x)=x$, $g(x) = x-1$ and $h(x) = x+1$ and you can see that your procedure allows you to prove that $x<x-1$.

Comment: You're right, thank you for the explanation and your time.